# Can't add array to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to send an array to mongodb, but the `res.json(user)` returns an empty `biddingGroup:[]` and mongodb document never has field biddingGroup appear. I've looked at stack posts and have seen suggestions for schema.
I've tried

```
biddingGroup: [{type: String}],
biddingGroup: [String],
biddingGroup: {type: String},
```

I haven't found a working schema that captures the data yet.

I even hardcoded biddingGroup: ['test'] too, but it never shows up.

app.js

```
app.put('/api/listings/:id', (req, res) =>

Post.update({
  id: req.query.id
}, {
  $set: {
    currentBid: req.query.currentBid,
    lastBidTimeStamp: req.params.lastBidTimeStamp,
    biddingGroup: ['test']
  }
}, {
  multi: false //set to false to ensure only one document gets updated
}).exec().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
})
    );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try this :- In Schema :: `biddingGroup: [String]` && Query :: `Post.update(
    { id: req.query.id },
    $set : {
    currentBid: req.query.currentBid,
    lastBidTimeStamp: req.params.lastBidTimeStamp,
    biddingGroup: ['test']
})` or if you've to replace entire document with new document :: `Post.update(
    { id: req.query.id },
    {
        currentBid: req.query.currentBid,
        lastBidTimeStamp: req.params.lastBidTimeStamp,
        biddingGroup: ['test']
    })`

Comment: I tried it both ways you've suggested with biddingGroup: [String] set in the mongoose model, but biddingGroup still returns as ```biddingGroup: []``` biddingGroup never makes it as a field in mongodb document

Comment: So does that id has only one matching id in db ? Can you run the query directly & check if there is any document being updated or not & also check that particular document is being updated properly..

Comment: The lastBidTimeStamp and currentBid values get updated when you place a bid. Here's a screenshot of console.log(data) https://postimg.cc/yktsSnzv    I don't really understand why it's not appearing in mongodb document because mongoose model has biddingGroup: [String] defined and the value is hardcoded to eliminate additional guessing of issue.

Comment: Are you using .update() or anything other like .findAndUpdate(), if you use others & console.log(data) then it would print the old document, you need to pass option {new : true} then new doc will be printed in data ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `exec()` at the end to run the query. That is the function that actually runs the request and returns you the promise. Plus your usage of the `update` function in general is off.

Try this:

```
Post.update({
  id: req.query.id
}, {
  $set: {
    currentBid: req.query.currentBid,
    lastBidTimeStamp: req.params.lastBidTimeStamp,
    biddingGroup: ['test']
  }
}, {
  multi: false //set to false to ensure only one document gets updated
}).exec().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I added your code and tried all three variations of defining biddingGroup in mongoose model that are listed at the top, but biddingGroup is still blank. Even with 'test' hardcoded. console.log(data) has biddingGroup looking like   ```biddingGroup: []```   I updated code above.